# Unable to install Ajenti-V on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I want to install Ajenti-V on my new server (Ubuntu 14.04).
At first I installed Ajenti as [documented here](http://support.ajenti.org/topic/349868-installing-on-ubuntu/).

Secondly I want to install Ajenti-V. And every time I try to `apt-get install ajenti-v` I get the error message `unable to locate package ajenti-v`.

Under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` I have the file `agent.list` with the following content:

> `deb http://repo.ajenti.org/debian main main ubuntu`

Does anybody know why I'm getting these error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [**the manual installation** documented here](http://support.ajenti.org/topics/1121-installing-on-ubuntu).

1. Add repository key:

   ```
   wget http://repo.ajenti.org/debian/key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. Add repository to /etc/apt/sources.list:

   ```
   echo "deb http://repo.ajenti.org/ng/debian main main ubuntu" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
3. Install the package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ajenti
   ```
4. Start the service:

   ```
   sudo service ajenti restart
   ```

After doing this, it worked for me.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference. Try to add the complete solution.

Comment: This way of Ajenti installation fixed the problem with missing websites section after Ajenti V installation. Basically "Quick automatic install" command `wget -O- https://raw.github.com/ajenti/ajenti/1.x/scripts/install-debian.sh | sh` installs a newer version that looks like still not supporting website management as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and then try it.

Remember, Ajenti has to be installed in order to use Ajenti-V.

what happens when you type in `service ajenti status` ?